# how to make jquery and AUI Script work in page which is response of an ajax request

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, liferay, alloy-ui

```
var searchLatestNews = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />searchLatestNews');
var paginator = searchLatestNews.one('.taglib-search-iterator-page-iterator-bottom');

if (searchLatestNews) {
    var parent = searchLatestNews;

    parent.plug(
        A.Plugin.IO,
        {
            autoLoad: false
        }
    );

    //paginator.one('.lfr-pagination-config').set('style','display:none');
    jQuery('div.lfr-pagination-config', '#<portlet:namespace />searchLatestNews').hide();

    paginator.all('a').on(
        'click',
        function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var uri = event.currentTarget.get('href');
            if (uri != 'javascript:;') {
                uri = event.currentTarget.get('href').replace(/p_p_lifecycle=0/i, 'p_p_lifecycle=2');
                uri = uri + '&p_p_resource_id=listAll';

                parent.io.set('uri', uri);
                parent.io.start();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the one occurrence of jQuery in your script that you use to call `.hide()` on a DOM element. Incidently, AUI has the same method available for you (check the [rosetta stone](http://alloyui.com/rosetta-stone/))

I assume `searchLatestNews.hide()` would do the trick.

If it doesn't, you might want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add an actual question, a description of what you want to achieve and what you already tried. So far your code leaves everything to guess, with only a hint in the question's title.

Comment: Hii Olaf thanks for your response, you are right that i have used jquery to hide a Dom element but the page where this content is getting loaded has the Jquery available and yes i have removed that line but my actual issue is if i am applying any jquery or AUI on dom elements then it doesn,t work , so it will be helpful if you can help me on the situaion i.e how jquery or AUI will work if it is loaded by ajax response